# Lua script gives error at line 448, at the end of script, what do I need to add to end the script?

Tags: lua, fivem

I have an error at the end of this Lua script, and I'm not sure how to end the script, the error is

[Script Error] https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BU2x.png

This is line 375 until the end of the script. I don't understand how I'm supposed to end this all. I'm very new to programming, Lua being the first language I'm attempting to learn. I get free scripts and edit them to my liking for my FiveM GTA RP server, and I'm not sure how to end this all. Thanks for all and any help, I appreciate it! :)

```lua
if dist <= 1 and not isProcessing then
            sleep = 5
            DrawText3D(process.x, process.y, process.z, '~b~E~w~ - Process Meth')
            if IsControlJustPressed(1, 51) then     
                isProcessing = true
                RegisterNetEvent('qb-coke:MakeMeth',function() 
                    QBCore.Functions.TriggerCallback("qb-meth:getMeth",function(mix)
                        if mix then
                            QBCore.Functions.Progressbar('making_meth', 'Making Meth', 15000, false, true, {
                                disableMovement = true,
                                disableCarMovement = true,
                                disableMouse = false,
                                disableCombat = true,
                            }, {}, {}, {}, function()  
                                TriggerServerEvent('qb-meth:processed')
                                ClearPedTasks(PlayerPedId())
                            end, function() -- Cancel
                                TriggerEvent('inventory:client:busy:status', false)
                                QBCore.Functions.Notify("Cancelled..", "error") 
                            end)
                        else
                            QBCore.Functions.Notify("You don't have all ingredients!", "error")
                        end
                    end)
                end)

function processing()
    local player = PlayerPedId()
    SetEntityCoords(player, process.x,process.y,process.z-1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, false)
    SetEntityHeading(player, 160.84)
    FreezeEntityPosition(player, true)
    playAnim("anim@amb@clubhouse@tutorial@bkr_tut_ig3@", "machinic_loop_mechandplayer", 30000)

    QBCore.Functions.Progressbar("meth-", "Making Meth", 0000, false, true, {
        disableMovement = true,
        disableCarMovement = true,
        disableMouse = false,
        disableCombat = true,
    }, {}, {}, {}, function() -- Done
        FreezeEntityPosition(player, false)
        LocalPlayer.state:set("inv_busy", false, true)
        TriggerServerEvent('qb-meth:processed')
        isProcessing = false
    end, function() -- Cancel
        isProcessing = false
        ClearPedTasksImmediately(player)
        FreezeEntityPosition(player, false)
    end)

end

function cooldown()
    Citizen.Wait(200)
    TriggerServerEvent('qb-meth:updateTable', false)
end

function playAnimPed(animDict, animName, duration, buyer, x,y,z)
    RequestAnimDict(animDict)
    while not HasAnimDictLoaded(animDict) do 
      Citizen.Wait(0) 
    end
    TaskPlayAnim(pilot, animDict, animName, 1.0, -1.0, duration, 49, 1, false, false, false)
    RemoveAnimDict(animDict)
end

    function playAnim(animDict, animName, duration)
        RequestAnimDict(animDict)
        while not HasAnimDictLoaded(animDict) do 
          Citizen.Wait(0) 
        end
     TaskPlayAnim(PlayerPedId(), animDict, animName, 1.0, -1.0, duration, 49, 1, false, false, false)
        RemoveAnimDict(animDict)    
    end
end
```

Comment: consider working on simpler code until you are more familiar with Lua's syntax.

Comment: Please use proper indentation, then you would immediately find the error yourself. And helps you to read the code.

Answer (score 1):

first hint: error message. The only if statement that comes into mind here is `if IsControlJustPressed(1, 51) then` ...

second hint: the code is properly indented so it is very obvious that there is no end a the indentation level of that if statement.

third hint: you have more key words that need an `end` than you have `end`s.

Check if you find the matching end for each keyword. Do this starting from the innermost scope.

At the end you'll find that you don't have an end for `if IsControlJustPressed(1, 51) then`...

Tip: If you can't do this in your head, delete everything that is syntactically correct until you find something that is not.